# React Source code: What does it mean by "real internal dependencies"

Tags: reactjs

I was browsing the React source code and noticed [ReactDOMFiberFBEntry.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/fb/ReactDOMFiberFBEntry.js).

This file has the following comment:

```
 // These are real internal dependencies that are trickier to remove:
```

What does it mean by "real internal dependencies" Internal to react itself, the React Dom? I'm sure this is blindingly obvious but i'm not quite sure. Also does the word "real" have much meaning in this case?

source:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2013-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

'use strict';

var ReactDOMFiber = require('ReactDOMFiberEntry');

Object.assign(
  ReactDOMFiber.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED,
  {
    // These are real internal dependencies that are trickier to remove:
    ReactBrowserEventEmitter: require('ReactBrowserEventEmitter'),
    ReactErrorUtils: require('ReactErrorUtils'),
    ReactFiberErrorLogger: require('ReactFiberErrorLogger'),
    ReactFiberTreeReflection: require('ReactFiberTreeReflection'),
    ReactDOMComponentTree: require('ReactDOMComponentTree'),
    ReactInstanceMap: require('ReactInstanceMap'),
    // This is used for ajaxify on www:
    DOMProperty: require('DOMProperty'),
    // These are dependencies of TapEventPlugin:
    EventPluginUtils: require('EventPluginUtils'),
    EventPropagators: require('EventPropagators'),
    SyntheticUIEvent: require('SyntheticUIEvent'),
  },
);

module.exports = ReactDOMFiber;
```

Comment: They refer to internal Facebook usage. there are things uncommitted publicly in github. afaik react team have a special react build for internal usage at Facebook.

Comment: The link you posted is broken, at least for me, I'm getting a 404. I'd recommend running Git Blame and reading the comments in Git that are related to changes to this line

Answer (score 13):

As noted by [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/3896#issuecomment-914036200), the `__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` object contains React internal functions and states. Those internals are not intended to be used from the React public APIs.

Dan wrote about it:

> No, it’s not safe to use. That’s why it has a scary name. We offer no guarantees about what will happen if you access things there. The behavior can change on any release. We strongly recommend against touching it in your library if you don’t want that library to break later.

Comment: I'm using it for detecting in a proxy based API whether React is rendering or not. Although it's better to sniff out the internals object instead of relying on that silly name: `import * as react from 'react'; const reactInternals = Object.entries(react).find(([, val]) => val.ReactCurrentOwner)[1]`